# Representar el caso contrario de una condición con el bloque while en C

Tags: c, condiciones, while

Tengo la variable **numSupporters** que debe cumplir la siguiente condición:

El número de aficionados (**numSupporters**) debe estar comprendido entre 1 y 10. En caso
contrario, debe mostrarse el siguiente mensaje de error y volver a pedir el dato.

**INVALID DATA, TRY AGAIN!**

Entiendo que en este caso habría que utilizar un bloque while, pero no se me ocurre cómo escribir la condición para que se muestre el error si numSupporters no está comprendido entre 1 y 10.

Gracias.

EDIT: ya lo he solucionado

````
while(numSupporters<0 || numSupporters>10)
     printf("INVALID DATA, TRY AGAIN!");
     printf("NUMBER OF SUPPORTERS (1-10)?");
     scanf("%d",numSupporters)```
````

Comment: no sabes como escribir un if para eso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tambien puedes hacerlo asi:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int numSupporters;

        printf("Ingrese el número de aficionados (entre 1 y 10): ");
        scanf("%d", &numSupporters);
       
    while((numSupporters < 1 || numSupporters > 10)) {
        printf("INVALID DATA, TRY AGAIN!\n");
        printf("Ingrese el número de aficionados (entre 1 y 10): ");
        scanf("%d", &numSupporters);
    }

    printf("Número de aficionados válido: %d\n", numSupporters);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tambien puedes hacerlo con un if de la siguiente manera

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int numSupporters;

    while (1) {
        printf("Ingrese el número de aficionados (entre 1 y 10): ");
        scanf("%d", &numSupporters);

        if (numSupporters >= 1 && numSupporters <= 10) {
            break; // El valor es válido, salimos del bucle while.
        } else {
            printf("INVALID DATA, TRY AGAIN!\n");
        }
    }

    // Aquí puedes usar numSupporters, que contendrá un valor válido entre 1 y 10.
    printf("Número de aficionados válido: %d\n", numSupporters);

    return 0;
}
```